# How to write @cucumberoptions as format="html:folderpath" in new version of cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

There is change in new version which do not allow to use format={}, says its deprecated. can anyone help how to write the same in new version generate a HTML report at the location mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`format` has been replaced with `plugin` so you can use:

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"progress", "html:target/cucumber-report.html"})
```